# npm install on chromebook

Tags: npm, chromebook

I just got myself a Chromebook but having some issues installing packages with npm install. I am in developer mode and also tried with root but still getting permission issues. Anyone else having these issues? I have also tried taking ownership of the folders by running `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /mnt/chromeos/` but no luck
Here is the permission issue I get when I try to run npm install:

````
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! dest /mnt/chromeos/MyFolder/node_modules/.bin/parser
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/mnt/chromeos/GoogleDrive/MyDrive/MyFolder/node_modules/.bin/parser'```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue. I figured it out. I had linked my android folder to the linux folder (when create a folder in a chromebook you can right click and "share with linux").

Well turns out these things don't play nice with symlinks.

Solution is create a new folder in you "linux files" directly (that isn't shared between the VM and ChromeOS) and run your command again. It should work.

Comment: Yes Garry I had the same. End up creating folders in my Linux container and from there on it worked. Your answer is very similar solution so will mark it as answer.