# ChromeOS error root/administrator during installing react app in VScode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install, google-chrome-os

I am using acer chromebook Version 107.0.5304.92 (Official Build) (32-bit).
I am installing npm/node using this command

The command to install node js on a chromebook is:
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -

after this command i can see node version and npm version then i run npx create-reat-app my-app it starts running after a long time it is throwing this error.

```
I am trying to run react app in vscode i installed vscode using this link
[text](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/12/03/chromebook-get-started)

when i run npx create-react
-app using terminal it works fine but then i cannot see my folder in files in chromebook.

i created one folder directly from terminal instal npm and react it worked fine but then i was unable to see my this very folder in files and i lost all my data once it updated.

i am new to chromeOs and do not know much.
```

```
kitty@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio$ npm -v
8.19.2
kitty@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio$ nodejs -v
bash: nodejs: command not found
kitty@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio$ node -v
v16.18.0
kitty@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio$ npx create-react-app brew-finder

Creating a new React app in /mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio/brew-finder.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

(##########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠙ reify:postcss-replace-overflow-wrap: timing reifyNod(##########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠼ reify:postcss-font-variant: timing reifyNode:node_mo(##########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠇ reify:yocto-queue: timing reifyNode:node_modules/jso(##########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠴ reify:@tootallnate/once: timing reifyNode:node_modul(##########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠋ reify:@jest/globals: timing reifyNode:node_modules/d(###########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠇ reify:@jest/test-sequencer: timing reifyNode:node_mo(###########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠏ reify:jest-resolve-dependencies: timing reifyNode:no(###########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠸ reify:locate-path: timing reifyNode:node_modules/pkg(###########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠸ reify:locate-path: timing reifyNode:node_modules/pkg(###########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠸ reify:locate-path: timing reifyNode:node_modules/pkg
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! dest /mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio/brew-finder/node_modules/.bin/parser
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio/brew-finder/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio/brew-finder/node_modules/.bin/parser'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio/brew-finder/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kitty/.npm/_logs/2022-11-09T07_55_51_950Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting brew-finder/ from /mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio
Done.
kitty@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio$ npm install -g create-react-app
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kitty/.npm/_logs/2022-11-09T08_04_36_296Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: I posted a fix for this on a duplicate issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502870/npm-install-on-chromebook

Comment: Thanks i created react app successfully but after that it says package.json file not found when i try to start npm

Comment: kitty@penguin:~/try-again$ npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/kitty/try-again/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/kitty/try-again/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kitty/.npm/_logs/2022-12-20T09_24_07_133Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

You somewhat messed with your npm's instalation and it now require root access to install global package (`-g` flag).
the quick fix is to use `sudo` to perform your installation

```bash
sudo npx create-react-app brew-finder
sudo npm i -g create-react-app
```

Comment: tried this but didnt worked adding code below

Comment: npm ERR!     /home/kitty/.npm/_logs/2022-11-09T08_49_53_736Z-debug-0.log
kitty@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio$ sudo npx create-react-app
Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app@5.0.1
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
sh: 1: create-react-app: Permission denied
kitty@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio$ sudo npx create-react-app my-brew
sh: 1: create-react-app: Permission denied
kitty@penguin:/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/Portfolio$