# npx create react app not working "Error: EACCES: permission denied"

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npx

i ran npx create react app on my terminal but got this error:

```
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js
npm ERR! dest /mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/codes/react chat app/new-react/node_modules/.bin/parser
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/codes/react chat app/new-react/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js' -> '/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/codes/react chat app/new-react/node_modules/.bin/parser'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../@babel/parser/bin/babel-parser.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/codes/react chat app/new-react/node_modules/.bin/parser'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/andrewkim4436/.npm/_logs/2023-04-29T05_59_45_704Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting new-react/ from /mnt/chromeos/MyFiles/codes/react chat app
Done.
```

i would appreciate if someone could explain what the error is and how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install on chromebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502870/npm-install-on-chromebook)